# Laravel says file does not exist but it does

Tags: php, laravel

I have this line:

```
$local_document_path = storage_path() . "/app/file/myfile.pdf";

$myfile = Storage::get($local_document_path);
```

And I get a FileNotFoundException error.

Now I checked the variable and seems correct, and I double checked again by copying the path to clipboard and pasting it:

```
dd($local_document_path == $copypasted_path)
```

It returns true. This means that the path is 100% correct, yet it does not work with storage. I have also tried by removing `storage_path();` and it does not work either.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dd($local_document_path = $copypasted_path)` returns true? This is an assignment not a comparison. Unless the value of $copypasted_path is boolean true, that can never return true

Comment: @Paras Sorry it was == not = I typed it wrong. It is still the same and it return true.

Comment: [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) say "Remember, all file paths should be specified relative to the 'root' location configured for the disk" but you've given an absolute path. That's likely the issue. Is there a folder called `app` *within* your `storage` folder in Laravel?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, absolutely.

Comment: If so, `Storage::get('app/file/myfile.pdf');` should do it, assuming `storage/app/file/myfile.pdf` a) exists and b) is readable by the webserver.

Comment: @ceejayoz You gave me the key. I checked filesystems.php and it was like this:  'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ] so I removed storage_path() and app and now it works. You may want to write this as answer.

Comment: Actually, looking at my Laravel config, the default `Storage` disk has a config of `'root'   => storage_path('app')`, so you need `Storage::get('file/myfile.pdf');`

Comment: Jinx! Yep, that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Storage::get` calls should use a path relative to the root of the storage disk. The default storage disk is configured to be `storage_path('app')`, so you'll need `Storage::get('file/myfile.pdf')`.