# File not found Error while downloading fies in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I'm not sure that do we have to have that zip file already created in the path before requesting it to download zip file?

Or

Do we need to have that `zipname` field available in Database to download to that particular file?

**Note:** I don't have `zipname` available in database. I'm using `job_id` field to get all the filename that needs to be downloaded in zip file.

I did check with the Zip file path that does not exist which makes sense. But here I'm trying to create a zip file and then download it. Wouldn't it be created and then download?

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ **FileNotFoundException**

> The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\ftek\ftekcsv2ritesh\ftekcsv2ritesh\storage\app\public\storage\bks\case_1\VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip" does not exist

**CONTROLLER: (function Download zip)**

```
            @$job_id = $request->job_id;
            @$filenames = DB::table('analytics_report')->where('job_id',$job_id)->get()->pluck('filename')->toArray();
            @$zipname = $request->job_id.'.zip';
            

            function forwardSlashes($path) {
                return str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
            }

            function case_1_path($zipname){
                $path = storage_path('app/public/storage/bks/case_1/'.$zipname);
                $path = forwardSlashes($path) ;
                return $path;
            }
          
            $zipFileName = case_1_path($zipname);

            $zip = new \ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipFileName, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach ($filenames as $filename){
                $relativefilepath = case_1_path($filename);
                $zip->addFile($filename, $relativefilepath);
            }
            $zip->close();
            
 

            return response()->download($zipFileName);
```

**DEBUGGING Local Variable**

```
$e: uninitialized
$filename: "1-ALLAHABAD-fl3cSTdW7IsNOa1nBiFD.pdf"
$filenames: array(3)
$filenames[0]: "1-ALLAHABAD-D0RjIWAHYcgXOSef7lLU.pdf"
$filenames[1]: "1-ALLAHABAD-Ad6X0Zi8oIN73Tf2p4Su.pdf"
$filenames[2]: "1-ALLAHABAD-fl3cSTdW7IsNOa1nBiFD.pdf"
$forwardpath: "C:\xampp\htdocs\ftek\ftekcsv2ritesh\ftekcsv2ritesh\storage\app\public\storage\bks\case_1\VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip"
$job_id: "VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf"
$path: "C:\xampp\htdocs\ftek\ftekcsv2ritesh\ftekcsv2ritesh\storage\app/public/storage/bks/case_1/VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip"
$request: Illuminate\Http\Request
$zip: ZipArchive
$zipname: "VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip"
$this: App\Http\Controllers\analyticsAuth\statementController
```

**CONTROLLER: (function Uploading PDF)**

```
                $filenameList = array();
                
                foreach ($files as $file){
                    
                    $filenamePre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file_id = random_strings(20); 
    
                    @$path_parts = pathinfo($filenamePre);
                    @$extension =  $path_parts['extension'];
                    @$filename=@$analytics_id.'-'.@$bankname.'-'.@$file_id.'.'.$extension;
        
                    @$file->move(base_path().'/storage/app/public/bks/case_1/', $filename);

                    array_push($filenameList,$filename);
```

Is there something related to symlink over here. I'm using Windows OS.

However, the Uploading function is working fine but not Downloading function.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is your question? you said it doesn't exist and you get FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Since I'm trying to create a zip file hence it won't be already there in my project.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel download method search for a file by configured storage relative path. So this `:\xampp\htdocs\ftek\ftekcsv2ritesh\ftekcsv2ritesh\storage\app\public\storage\bks\case_1\VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip` wont work. This `public\storage\bks\case_1\VQAzwHskpuxW9j1c8iPf.zip` should.

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705168/12436158